# How to get last modified username(email) or even name?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I am looking to get the last modified username or name of the user that last modified a file on Google Drive. This is what I have:

```
while (trashedFiles.hasNext()) {

   var trashedFile = trashedFiles.next();               
   var trashedName = trashedFile.getName();
   var trashedURL  = trashedFile.getUrl();
   var fileID      = trashedFile.getId()
   var trashedUpdated =  Utilities.formatDate(trashedFile.getLastUpdated(), timezone, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm");
   var trashedCreated =  Utilities.formatDate(trashedFile.getDateCreated(), timezone, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm");
   //var LastModifiedBy = Drive.Files.get([fileID]).lastModifyingUserName();
   var LastModifiedBy = Drive.Files.get([fileID]).lastModifyingUser();

}
```

I get this error: 
TypeError: Cannot call property lastModifyingUser in object

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope This will help:

https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/revisions

Please find the property by the name : lastModifyingUserName

Let me know if I am mistaken.

Comment: Perfect!! 
var LastModifiedBy = Drive.Files.get([fileID]).lastModifyingUser.displayName(); works!!!

Comment: I am glad it worked for you!. Please mark it as an answer to help other friends here :)