# Pb my script Google app script search in google drive with one word

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a problem with my script, I would like it to search all folders and subfolders for files with this word in them.
But it only stops at the first folder.
Thank you for your help

```
    function doGet(){
   return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('search').setXFrameOptionsMode(HtmlService.XFrameOptionsMode.ALLOWALL);
}

function idevlupSearch(sparams) {
  if (sparams.length==0){
        return `<em style='color:blue'> Champs de saisie vide`;
  }; 
  
  //Folder start 
  var folderName = "0-CentreDeRessources" ;
  var listSearch = [];

  var folder = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(folderName);  
  
  while (folder.hasNext()) 
    {
      Logger.log(folder);
      var files = folder.next().searchFiles('title contains "'+sparams+'" or fullText contains "'+sparams+'"');
      while (files.hasNext()) 
      { 
        var file = files.next(); 
        listSearch.push("<li> <a href='"+file.getUrl()+"'>"+file.getName()+"</a>"+file+"</li>"); 
      
      }
    }
  
  Logger.log(listSearch); 
  
  if (listSearch.length > 0) {
    listSearch.unshift("<ul>");
    listSearch.shift("</ul>");
    return listSearch;
  }else{
    return `<em style='color:red'> Pas de document trouvé !`;
  }
  
}
```

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand `I would like it to search all folders and subfolders for files with this word in them.`. Can I ask you about the detail of your question?

Comment: Oh. It comes from my English which is not very good :-).
In fact, I want to search in all the folders, the names of the files which have a word which I pass in parameter.
Example : 
If I search for the word "car", I would like as result:
- Root folder/subfolder1/subfolder 2/ vehicle.doc
- Root folder/subfolder 1/subfolder 2/subfolder 3/ Mustang.doc
...
Do you understand better? 
The result is returned in a list in an html file.

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your replying, the filenames and folder names of `Root folder/subfolder1/subfolder 2/ vehicle.doc` and `Root folder/subfolder 1/subfolder 2/subfolder 3/ Mustang.doc` don't include the value of `car`. In this case, can I ask you about the logic for retrieving the filename of `vehicle.doc` and `Mustang.doc` using `car`? And I cannot imagine your goal from `The result is returned in a list in an html file.`. I apologize for this.

Comment: Very good point.  The original system will have several hundred files. And you don't want to search file by file or talk about a specific word. 

It is clear that the word could be keywords example (car;mustang) and that the result would be sorted by the number of occurrences found. 
Example :
  In the file mustang.doc
3 times the word car has been found 
5 times the word mustang has been found 

One can push the search system very far...

Comment: Thank you for replying. In your goal, you want to search the value of `car` from both the file content and the filename. Is my understanding correct? And, from your sample result of `Root folder/subfolder1/subfolder 2/ vehicle.doc - Root folder/subfolder 1/subfolder 2/subfolder 3/ Mustang.doc`, in your situation, you want to search the files under `subfolder 2` including only one folder of `subfolder 3`. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: I am not interested in searching in the file name but in the content. And yes, in all the sub-folders.

Comment: Thank you for your interest in my problem :-)

Comment: Thank you for replying. In your goal, you don't want to create the path including all subfolder names. You just want to search the files under the subfolders and want to retrieve the searched filenames. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Yes exactly and be able to open the files found

Comment: Although unfortunately, I have some unclear points in your question, I proposed a modified script as an answer by guessing your situation. Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstood your question and that was not useful, I apologize.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- From the discussions in the comment, you don't want to create the path including all subfolder names. You just want to search the files under the subfolders and want to retrieve the searched filenames.

In this case, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

```js
function idevlupSearch(sparams) {
  if (sparams.length == 0) {
    return `<em style='color:blue'> Champs de saisie vide`;
  };
  var folderName = "0-CentreDeRessources";
  var folder = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(folderName).next();
  var searchFlies = (folder, res = []) => {
    var files = folder.searchFiles(`(title contains '${sparams}' or fullText contains '${sparams}') and trashed=false`);
    while (files.hasNext()) {
      var file = files.next();
      res.push({name: file.getName(), url: file.getUrl()});
    }
    var folders = folder.getFolders();
    while (folders.hasNext()) searchFlies(folders.next(), res);
    return res;
  }
  var listSearch = searchFlies(folder);
  return listSearch.length > 0 ? listSearch.reduce((s, {name, url}) => s += `<li><a href='${url}'>${name}</a></li>`
    , "<ul>") + "</ul>" : `<em style='color:red'> Pas de document trouvé !`;
}
```

#### Note:

- I cannot understand that how the function `idevlupSearch` is run. But, in your script, Web Apps is used. **In this case, when you modified the Google Apps Script, please modify the deployment as a new version. By this, the modified script is reflected in Web Apps. Please be careful this.**
- You can see the detail of this in the report of "[Redeploying Web Apps without Changing URL of Web Apps for new IDE](https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/ebf92d8f427d02d53989d6c3464a9c43)".

#### About some unclear points, I guessed as follows.

- I couldn't understand `file` of `</a>"+file+"</li>` in your script. Because in your script, `file` is an object of Class File. So in this modification, I modified to `<li><a href='${url}'>${name}</a></li>`.
- I couldn't understand whether there are several same folder names of "0-CentreDeRessources". So in this modification, I guessed that the folder name of "0-CentreDeRessources" is only one folder in your Google Drive.
- I couldn't understand the output from the function `idevlupSearch`. In your script, a text or an array is returned from the function `idevlupSearch`. But I cannot know about the function which calls `idevlupSearch`. So in this modification, a text is returned.

If my modification was not in the direction you expect, please modify the above script for your actual situation.

Comment: Excellent, that's exactly 
Thank you very much, I really liked how you came up with the ending,

Comment: @Anubis Thank you for replying and testing. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.

Comment: last small question, is it possible to know the name of the last user who modified the file?

Comment: @Anubis About your new question of `last small question, is it possible to know the name of the last user who modified the file?`, I think that in this case, it is required to retrieve `lastModifyingUser` using Drive API. This can be seen at https://stackoverflow.com/q/32799001 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/28017673